# In Rust, is "as" an operator?

Tags: rust, grammar, binary-operators

The Rust Reference presently says the following about [the `as` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#type-cast-expressions):

> #### 7.2.12.5 Type cast expressions
>
> A type cast expression is denoted with the binary operator `as`.
>
> Executing an `as` expression casts the value on the left-hand side to the type on the right-hand side.
>
> An example of an `as` expression:
>
> ```
> fn average(values: &[f64]) -> f64 {
>   let sum: f64 = sum(values);
>   let size: f64 = len(values) as f64;
>   sum / size
> }
> ```

(Also, since it will be relevant:

> #### 7.2.12.8 Operator precedence
>
> The precedence of Rust binary operators is ordered as follows, going from strong to weak:
>
> ```
> as
> * / %
> + -
> << >>
> ```

)

Naïvely using this as an operator doesn't seem to work:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 100 as u16 << 8;
}
```

Doesn't actually compile:

```
% rustc testing.rs
testing.rs:2:24: 2:25 error: expected type, found `8`
testing.rs:2    let x = 100 as u16 << 8;
```

With parentheses — `let x = (100 as u16) << 8;` — it compiles. The parens aren't required in the example in the reference, but seem to be here. What's the exact syntax here? Are parentheses required unless this is the only thing right of an `=`? Or am I just doing something wrong?

<sub>It is a bit weird that this is called an operator, as the RHS would seem to need to be a type, and typically, I think of an operator as taking two expressions…</sub>

Comment: The only surprising thing here is that the Operator Precedence seems off in light of your experiment. Otherwise, I don't see the issue with `as` being an operator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The trick here is `as` takes a type on its right hand side, i.e. the grammar of `as` looks something like: is `expression 'as' type`. The expression after the `as` looks a bit like (the start of) a type, it's trying to parse `u16<<...` as if `u16` had a type parameter (an example of a type with a prefix like that would be `Foo<<T>::Bar>`).

This is basically just behaviour particular to `<<` because it looks like the type parameter delimiters. If one uses an operator that can't appear after the leading identifier in a type, it works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 100 as u16 - 8;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the meaning of `<T>` in your example? I.e., how is `<T>` not preceded by an identifier, like `Foo<Baz<T>::Bar>`?

Comment: It's part of "fully qualified paths", e.g. to refer to the asociated type `Bar` in the implementation of a trait `Trait` for a type `T`, one can write `<T as Trait>::Bar` which can (sometimes) be abbreviated as `<T>::Bar`. (Either the abbreviation or the full form is enough for this purpose: there's valid types with leading `<`.)