# How do I represent C's "unsigned negative" values in Rust code?

Tags: rust, ffi, signedness

I'm calling the [`ResumeThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-resumethread) WinAPI function from Rust, using the [winapi crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi).

The documentation says:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the thread's previous suspend count.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is (DWORD) -1.

How can I effectively check if there was an error?

In C:

```c
if (ResumeThread(hMyThread) == (DWORD) -1) {
    // There was an error....
}
```

In Rust:

```
unsafe {
    if ResumeThread(my_thread) == -1 {
            // There was an error....
    }
}
```

```
the trait `std::ops::Neg` is not implemented for `u32`
```

I understand the error; but what is the best way to be semantically the same as the C code? Check against `std::u32::MAX`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C, `(type) expression` is called a *type cast*. In Rust, you can perform a type cast by using the `as` keyword. We also give the literal an explicit type:

```
if ResumeThread(my_thread) == -1i32 as u32 {
    // There was an error....
}
```

I would personally use `std::u32::MAX`, potentially renamed, as they are the same value:

```
use std::u32::MAX as ERROR_VAL;

if ResumeThread(my_thread) == ERROR_VAL {
    // There was an error....
}
```

See also:

- [How do I convert between numeric types safely and idiomatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28273169/155423)
- [Is casting between integers expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44685633/155423)
- [What is the difference between From::from and as in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48795329/155423)
- [In Rust, is "as" an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32102518/155423)
- [How do I convert a boolean to an integer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55461617/155423)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, either `std::u32::MAX` or perhaps `!0u32` (the equivalent of C `~0UL`, which emphasizes the fact that it's the all-bits-set value for the given type).